# Increment a {key: value} within an array of objects with MongoDB Mongoose driver

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, increment

I have a document that looks similar to this:

```
{
    'user_id':'{1231mjnD-32JIjn-3213}',
    'name':'John',
    'campaigns':
        [
            {
                'campaign_id':3221,
                'start_date':'12-01-2012',
                'worker_id': '00000'
            },
            {
                'campaign_id':3222,
                'start_date':'13-01-2012',
                'worker_id': '00000'
            },
            ...
            etc
            ...
        ]
}
```

Say I want to increment the `campaign_id` of element 7 in the `campaigns` array.
Using the [dot](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation) with the mongoose driver, I thought I could do this:

`camps.findOneAndUpdate({name: "John"}, {$inc: {"campaigns.7.campaign_id": 1}}, upsert: true, function(err, camp) {...etc...});`

This doesn't increment the `campaign_id`.
Any suggestions on incrementing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but your `upsert` option isn't formatted correctly.

Try this:

```js
camps.findOneAndUpdate(
    {name: "John"}, 
    {$inc: {"campaigns.7.campaign_id": 1}}, 
    {upsert: true},
    function(err, camp) {...etc...});
```

Comment: For some reason I do not understand, if I say: `var update = 'campaigns.' + position + ".campaign_id"` and then `$inc: {update: 1}` does not work (where `position` is an integer).  But works fine if I spell it out like above: `$inc: {"campaigns.7.campaign_id": 1}`.  Do you know why?

Comment: Because you can't use a variable as a key name in a JavaScript immediate object.  So you have to build up your update object programmatically.  `var update = {$inc: {}}; update.$inc['campaigns.' + position + ".campaign_id"] = 1;`

Comment: ahh... interesting.  Thanks!